# Get history all commands run as Administrator in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows

I want to get a report of all the commands run as administrator in a given time frame.
By mistake I made some changes as administrator (like move files, etc) and I would like to get exactly the list of commands I run in that mode before switching to normal mode.

There must be a log file or something - maybe with some tool from the  sysinternals suite?
I'm sort of new in Windows so any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I didn't realise I was in administrator mode and performed some actions in the terminal, so I would like to know what I did in admin mode

Comment: Going forward set up transcripts in your PS profile. Make sure to set it for the elevated profile. This will log the commands and also all the output along with other data.

Comment: @ranemirusG did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to get a report of all the commands run

The only thing I can think of requires that you still have the PowerShell session open. Then you can run `Get-History`:

> The `Get-History` cmdlet gets the session history, that is, the list of commands entered during the current session.

Source: [Get-History (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history?view=powershell-7.3)

If you have closed the session then I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if it's in:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

or:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

with help of env var.

It logs Powershell 5-7 from what I see, not sure about other versions. There are no timestamps though.